# How to show $f(X)$ and $g(X)$ are positively correlated for a random variable $X$, if $f$ and $g$ are non-decreasing and bounded?

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

How to show $\mathrm{cov}( f(X),g(X)) \geq 0$ for  a random variable $X$, if $f$ and $g$ are non-decreasing and bounded?

I know a coupling method by introducing an independent copy of $X$ (page $2$, [here](https://notendur.hi.is/~hermann/iid/csr/samples/chapter1.pdf)). What's the straightforward way of showing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{P}_X$ denote the distribution of $X$. Then

$$\begin{align} \mathbb{E}\bigg[ \big(f(X)-\mathbb{E}f(X) \big) \cdot \big( g(X)-\mathbb{E}g(X) \big) \bigg] &= \mathbb{E}\big(f(X) \cdot g(X) \big) - \mathbb{E}f(X) \cdot \mathbb{E}g(X) \\ &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \big( f(x)-f(y) \big) \cdot \big( g(x)-g(y) \big) \, d\mathbb{P}_X(y) \, d\mathbb{P}_X(x) \end{align}$$

where the last equality follows simply by expanding the brackets. By the monotonicity of $f$, $g$,

$$ \big( f(x)-f(y) \big) \cdot \big( g(x)-g(y) \big) \geq 0 \qquad (x,y \in \mathbb{R})$$

and so the claim follows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should admit "the last equality" is not straightforward to me.