# Is $ \mathbb{E}f(X)g(X) \ge \mathbb{E}f(X)\mathbb{E}g(X) $ always true?

Tags: probability

Assume that $f$ and $g$ are non-negative functions. The inequality is true when f=g=identity (using the non-negativity of variance). Is it true in general?

Comment: No, it is not true in the gerenal case. Consider $f = \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$ and $g =  \mathbb{1}_{[1,2]} $, with $X$ uniform on $[0,2]$

Comment: Thanks. It isn't true for Boolean rvs either. I miscalculated.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440337/how-to-show-fx-and-gx-are-positively-correlated-for-a-random-variable-x